# Is there a mysql unix_timestamp function in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Let me keep it simple , Is there a mysql function unix_timestamp(datetime) in SQLAlchemy ?
or is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 5):

SQLAlchemy has support for arbitrary SQL functions. See http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html#functions.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

for row in conn.execute(select([func.unix_timestamp("a_datetime_column")], ...)):
    # ...
```

Comment: can it be used for other database engines ?

Comment: No. ``func.NNN`` is a reference to a SQL function with name NNN, The db engine must support NNN. Certain function names are known by SQLAlchemy and are given special treatment, see http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html#functions and http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func

Comment: How to apply this to: `analys = Analyzes.query.filter_by(id=id).first()`?